# Finding limit of sequence $a_n=\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given sequence $a_n=\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}$, where $\alpha(n)$=total no. of primes by which $n$ is divisible, find $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$. 
Example: $\alpha (8)=1$, as $2$ is the only prime by which $8$ is divisible.

Observing that $\alpha(n)\lt n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, the given sequence is bounded. Then I tried using the fact that every $n$ has prime factorisation.

But I don't know how to proceed further. Any hints?

Comment: Hint : Fix $k$. What is the smallest $n$ such that $\alpha(n) = k$? Look at $\frac kn$, how does it look for the first few values of $k$?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: I tried with $k=5$ and then I think that $n:\alpha(n)=k$ is $2.3.5.7.11$ but I think that it will give only lower bound (something greater than $0$), which I think will not evaluate the limit.

Comment: It won't give just a lower bound, it will very much give an upper bound, as the below answer illustrates. See, the point is that $\alpha(n)$ is much, much smaller than $n$, and one can quantify that, but I wanted you to see that with your own eyes for the first few values.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: I don't understand the $\log_2n$ part in below answer.

Comment: I will explain it. Since we must chat, can you come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi) to understand this?

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but if one is stuck, it can be useful as motivation to see that since $\alpha(n)=1$ infinitely often, the limit must be $0$ if it exists. Then one could focus on trying to prove $\lim a_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You can have a stricter bound than just $n$ for $\alpha(n)$. If every prime factor were a $2$ and repeated prime factors were allowed, then $\alpha(n) = \log_2(n)$, which is an upper bound because other prime factors have to be larger than $2$. Then, an upper bound on the limit is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log_2(n)}{n}$$

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. That's an amazing solution. But I don't understand how $\alpha(n)=\log_2 (n)$. Clearly this is not true. Perhaps you meant $\alpha(n)\le\log_2 (n)$? And I verified it using Induction. But how did you come up with $\log_2n$? I'll be grateful if you please make me understand that. 

Comment: I meant that $\log_2(n)$ is an upper bound, so $\alpha(n) = \log_2(n)$ in the "worst" case.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting an answer here. I would like to thank @Teresa Lisbon who's helped me a lot to solve this exercise.

Since every natural no. $n$ has a prime factorization, suppose that $n=n_1^{p_1}n_2^{p_2}\cdots n_k^{p_k}$ for prime nos. $n_i$'s where $i\in\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\}$. It follows that $\phi(n)=k$ as for every $i\in\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\}$, we have prime no. $n_i$ such that $n_i|n$.

$\begin{align}
\log_2n &=p_1\log_2n_1+p_2\log_2n_2+\cdots+p_k\log_2n_k\\
        &\ge p_1\log_22+p_2\log_22+\cdots+p_k\log_22\\
        &=p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_k \ge 1+1+\cdots+1 \text{  ($k$ times)}=k\\
\implies &\log_2n\ge k= \phi(n)\\
\implies &0\le\frac{\phi(n)}{n}\le\frac{\log_2n}{n}\end{align}$ $\tag 1$ 
Since $n^{\frac 1{n}}\to 1$, by continuity of $\log_2n$ we have $\frac{\log_2n}{n}=\log_2(n^{\frac 1{n}})\to \log_2(1)=0$

By squeeze theorem in $(1)$, it follows that $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}\to 0$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Madam, I have posted my answer here.Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Great! +1. By the way, you need to stick @TeresaLisbon together, otherwise it won't inform me. There was a space between Teresa and Lisbon when you wrote it. You will have to write it without spaces next time. Also, it is madam, you can say Senorita Teresa, I like the ring to that.

Comment: Sure, I'll remember that @TeresaLisbon. I have changed "Sir" to "Madam" in my earlier comment.Thanks a lot Senorita Teresa madam. 

Comment: You are welcome!